# Filtered results fields in grails

Tags: grails, foreign-keys

Hi I am new in Grails and would like to find out how do I have filtered results of two fields in grails. Should i do it in view, or should i do it in domain class? How do i do it?

In the following example, I have 3 classes:

1. Country
2. State
3. Address

The field State should display only filtered results based on Country. Right now all the states in the State object is presented. The following screenshot depicts this problem.

[All the states are listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uP24.png)

The following are my codes.

```
class Country {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String  countryName
    static  hasMany = [state : State ]

}

class State {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String  stateName
    static  belongsTo = [ country : Country ]

}

class Address {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String  line1
    String  line2
    Country country
    State   state

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using scaffolding?

If so Grails is going to render all of the appropriate form controls unless you exclude them e.g.

```
static constraints = {
   country display:false
}
```

However I don't think you need to associate Country with Address because there's an association between Address and State which also has an association with a Country so the association between an Address and a country will be implicit after selecting a state.

**EDIT 1**

If you want to keep the current model you'll probably have to move away from scaffolding and implement the action and gsp yourself e.g.

controller:

```
def create() {
    def states
    if ( params.country ) {
        states = State.findByCountry(params.country)
    }
    [countries: Country.all, states: states]
}
```

gsp:

```
<g:select class="form-control" 
    name="country"
    from="${countries}"
    optionKey="${it}"
    value="${params.country}"
    required="required"
    onchange="submit()"
    noSelection="['':'Select country']" />

<g:if test="${params.country}">
    <g:select class="form-control" 
        name="state"
        from="${states}"
        optionKey="${it}"
        value="${params.state}"
        required="required"
        noSelection="['':'Select state']" />
</g:if>
```

The above should be treated as pseudo code to give an idea of possible solution

Comment: Thanks Mike! You are right on the association between address and country. The association between Address and Country is implicit with State.

Comment: However, to make the selection more user friendly (there can be thousand of states in the world), how do i only display the states from countries which the user has selected? This will greatly reduce the choices the user has. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Updated answer with details on possibly method of keeping current model

Comment: Thank you Mike! Really appreciate your helps!

Comment: @YSL If the answer helps can you accept it or up vote, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers